# Oracle Index is not used when compare timestamp with <= or >=

Tags: sql, oracle

I have indexes on two columns of type Timestamp(2) START_DATE and END_DATE and a query with WHARE clause like:

```
WHERE C.START_DATE <= sysdate
  AND sysdate <= C.END_DATE
```

The explain plan makes TABLE ACCESS FULL instead of Index range scan.

-If I change `<=` to `=` the index is used.

-If I change `sysdate` to `systimestamp` it's worse in the explain plan:

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION(C.START_DATE))<=SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP(6))
```

with FULL SCAN again.

-Using `TO_TIMESTAMP` brings the desired index range scan:

```
WHERE C.START_DATE <= TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02 14:10:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
         AND TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02 14:10:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF') <= C.END_DATE
```

but I need to use the current date.

Can someone explain why that happens?

EDIT:
These are simplified versions of the query, but the same behavior appears. 
Explain plans.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
         select * 
           from communication c
            WHERE C.CAMPAIGN_START_DATE <= sysdate
         AND sysdate <= C.CAMPAIGN_END_DATE;
```

Plan hash value: 4120205924

```
-------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name          |
-------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |               |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| COMMUNICATION |
-------------------------------------------
```

.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
         select * 
           from communication c
            WHERE C.START_DATE = sysdate
         AND sysdate = C.END_DATE;
```

Plan hash value: 1474125303

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                        |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | COMMUNICATION          |
|   2 |   BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS    |                        |
|   3 |    BITMAP AND                    |                        |
|   4 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|                        |
|   5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | COMMUNICATION_START_DT |
|   6 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|                        |
|   7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | COMMUNICATION_END_TD   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show us the complete execution plan (edit your question and add it as _formatted_ text)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the explain plans.

Comment: you have removed some important parts of the plan: the estimated row counts

Comment: `SYSDATE` is a `DATE` type. Does it work better with `LOCALTIMESTAMP` which is a `TIMESTAMP` value?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes that works and the DB scans by index now. Thnaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with today day in timestamp? `TO_TIMESTAMP ('27-oct-15 14:10:10.123000'` ?  Doesnt make sense you compare the query using two different days.

My guess is using current date and `<=` will mean check most of the rows anyway. That mean using the index wont give much benefit

Try this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ....
WHERE C.START_DATE <= sysdate
  AND sysdate <= C.END_DATE
```

If both `COUNT(*)` are very similar mean there isnt any benefit on using the index because will need scan the full table anyway.

Comment: It's around 150 000 for count(*) and around 60 000 with the where clause

Comment: Can you try with a composite index for `(C.START_DATE, C.END_DATE)` ? Also did you try your sample with timestamp usind today as date?

Comment: IF you're bringing back 1/3 of the data EvGeni - then I'm not surprised it is choosing to just do a full scan rather than scan two indexes, merge the results to find the intersection set, then finally go and do each table lookup.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton That is probably why the sample  with `TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02` use the index. That query probably return much less rows.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks, that answers my question.